# Make a select2_multiple sortable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

How do we make a `select2_multiple` sortable? I have a `users` table and a `badges` table. Naturally, I want to have a `user_badge` pivot table which will keep track of all the badges a user has and also sort it based on the order that I define using the `select2_multiple`.

Currently, I have my `setupCreateOperation()` setup as follows:

```php
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'badges_multi',
        'label' => 'Badges',
        'type' => 'select2_multiple',
        'attribute' => 'internal_name',
        'entity' => 'badges_multi',
        'model' => 'App\Models\Badges',
        'pivot' => true,
        'sortable' => true,
        'sortable_options' => [
            'handle' => '.my-custom-handle',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

This returns the `select2_multiple` but the input is not sortable, i.e. I can drag and drop to rearrange. It only returns badges in alphabetical order

Answer (score 2):

The `select_multiple` field does not have the ordering functionality.

To order you can use the [select_and_order field](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#select_and_order-pro)  or the [repeatable field](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#repeatable-pro)

You can also create a custom version of the `select_multiple` field that has the order functionality if you want to implement it that way.

Doing `php artisan backpack:field select_multiple_with_order --from=select_multiple` would create you a new file in your resources folder that is equal to Backpack select_multiple, from there you can add the functionality you need, and re-use it in other cruds if you need it there too.

Wish you the best.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Pedro. How do I use the `select_and_order` to return the data to the frontend?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you mean by frontend, create and update operation forms ? You can check the field source code to have a better understanding of how the field works under the hood and extract some functionality you need elsewere.

Comment: Thanks for this, @Pedro. I switched to using select_and_order